# How many grades are there in learning the drums?

Tags: learning, drums, instruments, percussion

I've gotten to grade 8 in the drums and I want to know how many more grades are left for me to finish.

Comment: On other instruments, Grade 8 is about the *starting level* for entering a music college or conservatoire. But after that level, there aren't any more numbered grade exams - you are likely to be specializing in some particular style of drumming or percussion. if you are serious about any type of music making, you only *stop* learning when you die!

Comment: Where are you located?  Some grading systems do continue beyond grade 8, e.g., the Royal Conservatory of Music.  I'm not familiar with grading for drums, however.

Answer (score 2):

The system of exams for schoolkids ends at Grade 8.  If you really want more exams, there are various diplomas and degrees.  But mostly people just go out and do it.  The job requires musicianship and experience even more, perhaps, than technique.  I make my living partly from playing piano, but can't remember when I was last required to play anything 'difficult'.